# python2-gobject on Arch linux ImportError: No module named gobject

Tags: python, twisted, pygtk, archlinux, pygobject

I have some example [file](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/_downloads/pbgtk2.py) (download URL) to understand how to create Twisted chat with GUI.

In this particular file I have an exception `ImportError: No module named gobject`. 
It's true, I have only `gi` and already installed:

```
sudo pacman -S python2-gobject
```

So I decide that this code for `python3`, and again fail. After `pip install twisted` I can't run code: `ImportError: cannot import name 'gtk2reactor'` appears.

How to run this code at least.

And how to prevent this in future, because I have the same error in many science packages for python.

P.S. installing from source impossible either.
`make` returns a lot of errors even if ./configure completes fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Juhaz from Freenode told me that the code in examples was pretty old and uses unmaintained bindings.

In case someone starts the same was as I am this question would be helpfull.
Try to look at `wkPython`, for example [this](http://wiki.wxpython.org/wxPythonAndTwisted) post.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to clarify your question a bit, but if you can't run code after you pip, or if your pip is broken a uninstall/reinstall of pip may be your best bet. 
If you did successfully download the package, then I would dive into where you installed it and make sure the package is for the correct version of python, and that it is installed.

Comment: `ImportError: No module named gobject` the main error